# Problem with SoftPwm from Microsoft.IoT.Devices.Pwm

Tags: pi-2, led, windows-iot, pwm

I'm new here, started working with RPI and Windows Core month ago. 
Currently I'am trying to control RGB Led Strip ( set light, turn on/off, dim) from RPI.

To achieve this I use RPI 2 model B V1.1, Windows IoT Core also using software based PWM. But somehow it doesn't work. When I debbug program lights are on but don't change color. I got feeling that software PWM doesn't work.

Here is my scheme: 
[image]

And my code:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.IoT.DeviceCore.Pwm;
using Microsoft.IoT.Devices.Pwm;
using Microsoft.IoT.Devices.Lights;
using Windows.Devices.Gpio;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.Devices.Pwm;



namespace WindowsIotPwmExample
{

    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        #region Member Variables
        private RgbLed led;
        private GpioController _gpio;
        private PwmPin _redPin;
        private PwmPin _greenPin;
        private PwmPin _bluePin;


        #endregion // Member Variables

        public MainPage()
        {

            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
        }

        private async void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Start GPIO
            _gpio = GpioController.GetDefault();

            // Create PWM manager
            var pwmManager = new PwmProviderManager();

            // Add providers
            pwmManager.Providers.Add(new SoftPwm());

            // Get the well-known controller collection back
            var pwmControllers = await pwmManager.GetControllersAsync();

            // Using the first PWM controller
            var controller = pwmControllers[0];

            // Set desired frequency

            controller.SetDesiredFrequency(140);
            var minFreq = controller.MinFrequency;
            var manFreq = controller.MaxFrequency;
            // Create light sensor
            _redPin = controller.OpenPin(4);
            _greenPin = controller.OpenPin(5);
            _bluePin = controller.OpenPin(6);
            led = new RgbLed()
            {
                // SoftPwm
                RedPin = _redPin,
                GreenPin = _greenPin,
                BluePin = _bluePin
            };
        }

        private void ColorPick_SelectedColorChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ColorPick.SelectedColor != null)
            {
                led.Color = ColorPick.SelectedColor.Color;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your circuit doesn't look right at all. Firstly, the brown wire doesn't seem connected to anything. Secondly, it's not clear at all how many pins each light has, what those pins are connected to, or what kind of lights they are, or what their specs are and how they're meant to be connected

Comment: @Jodes basically brown wire connected to LED Strip 12V+ pin and other wires are to RED, Green and Blue pins of led strip.